# How to access shortcut in illustrator for showing the grid?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shortcuts

I'm a new user on graphic design stack exchange, I will try to earn some point, here is my first answer :

I've got some difficulty to show/hide the grid with shortcut. Everything that I need to access via F button like here F7+apple doesn't work. Don't you have any idea on :
- How to make my own short cut ?
- How to access F buttons without loosing sound volume control and light screen. I know, that I can change through this buttons via preference system...
- Where to find a good list for shortcut in illustrator ?

Wt's the easiest solution ?
Thanks Nicolas from Paris, France.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm confuzzled. As far as I know, the shortcut for showing or hiding the grid in Illustrator is <kbd>Option / Apple</kbd>+<kbd>'</kbd> (as in the single quote key). That doesn't involve any function keys.

To change keyboard shortcuts to you liking, go have a peek at `Edit > Keyboard Shortcuts` or press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Control / Option</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.

Comment: We don't have the same version my illustrator is in french and also I don't think we have the same keyboard mine is "azerty". Anyway, I didn't know it was so easy for editing short cut, I will change this right away... Thanks for you help !!!

Comment: Then just check in the `View` menu what the right shortcut is for `Show Grid`, or whatever that is in French. 'Presente rastre?'

Comment: It was _apple+F7_ know I've changed for _apple+'_ like you've suggested... I don't know what does mean : 'Presente rastre?'How do you make buttons shortcode here ?

Comment: That was me doing a lame effort at French, trying to point out the 'Show grid' option. Should be something like 'montrer réseau'?

Comment: hahaha no it's : "afficher/masquer la grille"

Comment: Don't you know a place where I can found shortcut already optimized for french people :) I'm not sure if I can import my short cut ? I've only seen option for export ? Maybe it's in edition>my parameter> import ?

Comment: I have no clue where to find something like that, but... it might be a nice question :)